# Links not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, mozilla

This code works in Internet Explorer and other browsers but does not work in Mozilla Firefox.
The code prompts the user to enter a password and if the correct password is entered the password protected page should open.
In Mozilla it displays a URL error or blank tab.
I have looked everywhere for an answer to this and tried using clickable links as opposed to a pop up window and that still does not work in Mozilla.
Pop up blocker is disabled, and I have tried safe mode in Mozilla with the same results.
I am also prompted by IE that scripts and ActiveX are restricted and have to enable before it can run.

Thanks in advance.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>PasswordProtectedPage</title>
</head>

<body>
<SCRIPT>
function passWord() {
  var testV = 1;
  var pass1 = prompt('Please enter the password:',' ');

  while (testV < 3) {
    if (!pass1)
    history.go(-1);

    if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "love") {
      window.open('/Users/Madeleine/Documents/moandmaddieindex.html');
      break;
    }

  testV += 1;
  var pass1 =
    prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.','Password');
  }

  if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3)
    history.go(-1);

  return " ";
}
</SCRIPT>

<!--Password prompt-->
<CENTER>
<FORM>
<input type="button" value="Enter Protected Area" onClick="passWord()">
</FORM>
</CENTER>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is how the page runs in IE:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAJ9H.png)

Comment: Where is your opening `<html>` tag? And I hope this is just for private use, because displaying your password in your source code is not really a good idea... It should be done on the server, where (normally) no one can see it.

Comment: Some things didn't translate well from my editor but my code had it and ran, just not in Firefox

Comment: check the folder location

Comment: It surprises me that it even works on IE and "other browsers", since you are technically not allowed to access nor process local files from the browser if it's not with the File API. (even with the File API the file MUST be selected by the user in order to work)

Comment: Did you check your error console? (Hit F12)

Comment: Definitely not trying to create a super secure script, just something that works at this point for practice. The folder location is definitely correct, I checked it over and over and it ran in IE like I said- just wondering why that could be. Tomasito665 what would you recommend doing or is there a resource you think would help me understand the issue? I am new to this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Checked the error console on Mozilla and nothing showed, it was just a blank tab

Comment: Are you using `http://` or `file://`?

Comment: You certainly _can_ create local html pages and open other local files with them, but, as Tomasito655 hints as, you should be using the `file://` "protocol" ... `file:///Users/Madeleine/...`  And there are other problems, such as blex mentioned, and your comparison should use triple-equals `...toLowerCase() === "thepassword"`

Comment: Tried using file:// and http::/, still no luck.